# Javers Spring setting specific field data during saving to history

Tags: java, spring, javers

I'm using Javers (5.2.6) with Spring integration and automatic saving entities to Javers history. My repositories look like

```
@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

Let say that `MyEntity` object looks like

```
class MyEntity {
    Long id;
    String code;
    Boolean active;
    Timestamp activeFrom;
    Timestamp activeTo;
}
```

`MyEntity.activeTo` field has default value like *MAX DATE* (very far date in the future) that is being stored unless the object is active. When I'm deactivating one entity, it's `activeTo` is being set to current timestamp.

The problem is that Javers is saving my entity versions (when I'm changing `code` field) with this *MAX DATE* value so snapshots looks like

```
CHANGE DATE | CODE | ACTIVE | ACTIVE_TO
 01.04.2019   'A'    TRUE     31.12.2099
 02.04.2019   'B'    TRUE     31.12.2099
 03.04.2019   'C'    TRUE     31.12.2099
 04.04.2019   'D'    TRUE     31.12.2099
 05.04.2019   'D'    FALSE    05.04.2019
```

And as you see it's impossible to realise how long a snapshot was active without fetching all snapshots, ordering them by *change date* and manually calculating the *active to* field *real* value.

How to solve this issue? I know that I can use Javers manually by calling history service by myself but I find it very convenience to use *@JaversSpringDataAuditable* because I have plenty of entities in my application

Is there any *post process* or *on-entity-saved-like* mechanism?

Comment: So you need to know **durations** between subsequent versions? If so, it looks like is should be modeled in your domain object as a part of your business logic. For now, Javers doesn't calculate it, although it could be a nice feature in Javers. Let's say `Duration snapshot.getVersionLifespan()`

Comment: Yes - in this specific situation I need duration but to be honest it would be great to have possibility of registering some custom 'onSaveListener' that could modify some fields of the model (like let say automatically generated comment for every version) just before persisting them to Javers tables. It's a pity it's not possible and you're right - I need to somehow implement this on the application side. Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: adding durations to CommitMetadata would be an easy task, think about contribution to JaVers